# Generator for placing images on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, generator

I have a list of paths to  around 90 images, now I want to place all of them on the canva,but only let's say 30 in one "row", but if I use

```
from tkinter import * 

def createCanvaImages(paths):
paths = ['list with the paths']
mainWin = Tk()
canva = Canvas(mainWin, width = 900, height = 300).pack()
for x in range(0, len(paths),):
    if x <= 30: #not sure if this places only 30 in one row
        y=x/3
    elif x > 30
        y=(x+24)/3
    elif x >= 60
        y=(x+48)/3
    img = PhotoImage(file = paths[x])
    canva.create_image(x+24, y, image = img)
    
 mainWin.mainloop()
```

it only shows the image from the last path

### EDIT

now shows all images on the canvas if the canvas isn't in a frame(thanks to Novel) but doesn't work if the canva is in a frame

```
from tkinter import * 

def createImagePaths(dct):
    paths=[]
    for i in range(len(masteries)):

        if dct.get(masteries[i]) == 0:
            file = masteries[i]+'.png'
            path = os.path.join(path_gray, file)
            paths.append(path)
            #create canvas image fnc
        if dct.get(masteries[i]) != 0:
            file = masteries[i]+'.png'
            path = os.path.join(path_colored, file)
            paths.append(path)
            
    return createCanvaImages(paths)

def createCanvaImages(paths):
    img_refs = []
    canva = Canvas(masteryFrame, height = 400).pack()
    for i, path in enumerate(paths):
            col,row = divmod(i,30)
            img = PhotoImage(file=path)
            canva.create_image( row*24, col*24, image = img, anchor = 'nw')
            img_refs.append(img)
        
root = Tk()
mainFrame = Frame(root)
mainFrame.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

masteryFrame = Frame(root)
masteryFrame.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your image references. The easiest way to do that is to just add them to a list. As a guess:

```
from tkinter import * 

def createCanvaImages(paths):
    canva = Canvas(masteryFrame, width = 900, height = 300)
    canva.pack()
    canva.img_refs = []
    for i, path in enumerate(paths):
        row, col = divmod(i, 30)
        img = PhotoImage(file = path)
        canva.create_image(col*24, row*24, image = img, anchor='nw') # each image is 24x24
        canva.img_refs.append(img)
```

Also, make sure you never put a widget initialization and layout on the same line. IOW, don't ever do this: `Widget(master).pack()`. Always put those on separate lines.

You should also learn about OOP and classes very soon. Using functions to build the UI like this will get very messy and buggy very quickly.

Comment: I tested your code and it placed all images on the canva but all on the left side and in two vertically rows and the images of the first row are only half on the [canva](http://imgur.com/a/TpdR7). And i try to implement  this one in bigger piece of code but there i have to use a frame or toplevel but in both it does not show the images(even with your solution), btw the images are all 24x24, and you wrote `paths[x]` but it should be `paths[i]`

Comment: elif x >= 60 will never execute because you previously test for > 30 which 60+ will be, and so since the >30 has executed the elif for >=60 will not be reached.  Reverse them, so >= 60 comes first.

Comment: @MushroomMauLa Oh, so I guess I got the rows / columns backwards. Just swap em to `col, row = divmod(i, 30)`.

Comment: @MushroomMauLa If this needs to be part of a class then your example should have been as well. In a class, the image references need to be an instance variable, so use `self.img_refs` instead of `img_refs`.

Comment: @MushroomMauLa I edited my post to fix those errors; try it now.

Comment: @Novel ok so now there are 2 horizontal rows but the in the first row are still only "half-shown"

Comment: @MushroomMauLa Hmm perhaps because it's centered. Try adding `anchor='nw'` (edited my code too).

Comment: That works ty! The function isn't part of a class, i'm going to update my coode above. Btw 'NW' gave me error it had to be 'nw' for me

Comment: Thank you really much for this great help! I'm currently trying to learn OOP and tried it with it too but i don't seem to get it right right now

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but is there any way to achieve [this](https://pastebin.com/S9agSz0n), i tried to dynamicly change the number of pictures which can be in a row after an condition  but some of the pictures just overwrite other or aren't in the place they should be. I should have asked for this while creating the question but i tought it wouldn't be a problem. Or can i place the images with .grid() on the canvas ?

Comment: You will have to clear all the images off the canvas first. It's not very elegant, but you could [use this](https://github.com/novel-yet-trivial/TkNamedColors/blob/master/colornames.py) for inspiration. If you still have issues, ask a new question.